# What is the motivation for defining the conductor of an abelian variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field, and let $A$ be an abelian variety over $K$. The conductor of the abelian variety is often defined as $2u+t+\delta$, where $u$, $t$ and $\delta$ are invariants related to the special fiber of the neron model of $A$ over the ring of integers of $K$. (See for example the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_of_an_abelian_variety). While I have seen this definition used in several texts, it has never been made clear to me where this definition came from, and why it is helpful.

What is the motivation for this odd definition? In what sense is it related to the conductor in number theory? In particular, is the following assertion correct?

#### Guess pertaining to motivation

Let $T_l$ be the Tate module of $A$, and let $L$ be the unique minimal field over $K$ such that $Gal(L)$ acts trivially on $T_l$. Let $G=Gal(L/K)$, and let the $G_i$'s be the lower numbering of the ramification of $L/K$. Then is the conductor of $A$ defined above the same as $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{|G_i|}{|G|}dim(T_l/(T_l^{G_i}))$? If so, where is this proven?

Comment: Your guess is not correct because $G$ will never be finite (consider the determinant, which is a power of the cyclotomic character), so neither the lower ramification groups nor their orders make sense.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is it some limit of this procedure, or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: First, restrict to inertia (the conductor measures ramification afterall). Then $G$ still need not be finite (it will be finite iff the reduction is pot. good), but inertia acts through a finite quotient on the semisimplification $V$ of the $l$-adic Tate module (to see this use Grothendieck's quasi-unipotence thm., for instance) and $\delta$ in your notation (= the Swan conductor) will be the Swan conductor of $V$, which will be given by a formula of  like you indicate, except you should start summing from $1$ rather than $0$ and replace $T_l$ by $V$.

Comment: One motivation is to define the conductor of an abelian variety
over a *global* field as a product of local factors.  The global conductor
is invariant under isogeny (so the local conductor has this property too),
and also enters into the functional equation for the $L$-function
of the variety.

Comment: Kestutis, that sounds exactly like the kind of explanation I want. Where can I read more about this? (In particular I am not familiar with "semisimplification" and "Grothendieck's quasi-unipotence thm".)

Noam, in that case what makes the definition of an abelian variety over a global field natural?

Comment: Or one can look at the mod-$l$ Galois representation, the Galois action on the $l$-torsion points. It is easy to see the Swan conductor on that representation is equivalent to the Swan conductor on the full $l$-adic representation. For proving theorems about the Swan conductor, it is often helpful to work mod $l$.

Comment: I don't know of an ideal reference, but you could try reading section 2 of Serre's "Facteurs locaux des fonctions zeta des varietes algebriques (definitions et conjectures)"; there the semisimplification step is done "by hand" and Grothendieck's result is referenced. To get the formula of the type you want from (10) there, express the Swan character as a sum of inductions of augmentation representations of ramification groups and use Frobenius reciprocity.

Comment: Kestutis, is the description you gave here the motivation for defining a conductor of an abelian group? What (originally) was the purpose of this notion?

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't know what's a conductor of an abelian group - conductors are typically associated to Galois representations (or close relatives of those). As far as I understand, in most situations a conductor is some sort of numerical measurement of ramification of the Galois representation at hand.

Comment: The motivation came from elliptic curves, where there is substantial literature (and history). The definition for abelian varieties is a direct generalization.

Answer (score 6):

The reference to Serre is good, but for a somewhat more elementary introduction (for elliptic curves), you could look at Chapter IV Section 10 of my book *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. It includes an explanation of why the tame part of the conductor can be read off from the reduction type (good, multiplicative, additive) of the elliptic curve, and why the wild part of the conductor is 0 for primes $p\ge5$. As noted in one of the comments, the wild part of the conductor is defined in terms of the action of inertia (and the higher inertia groups) on the $\ell$-torsion $E[\ell]$, so one can use the definition that you gave with $T_\ell(E)$ replaced by the finite Galois module $E[\ell]$. There's also a proof that the exponent of the conductor $f(E/K)$ over a local field $K$ with normalized valuation $v_K$ satisfies
$$ f(E/K)\le 2+3v_K(3)+8v_K(2). $$
(This was generalized to abelian varieties by Lockhart, Rosen, and me [1], and then Brumer and Kramer [2] gave the best possible upper bounds.)

Again for elliptic curves, there is a also the beautiful formula of Ogg [3] and Saito [4] relating the minimal discriminant $\text{Disc}_{E/K}$, the exponent of the conductor $f(E/K)$, and the number of components on the special fiber of the Neron model $m(E/K)$:
$$
  v_K(\text{Disc}_{E/K}) = f(E/K) + m(E/K) - 1.
$$
Ogg proved every case except char($K)=0$ and residue characteristic 2, while Saito gave a more conceptual proof that covers all cases

[1] Lockhart, P., Rosen, M. and Silverman, J., An upper bound for the
conductor of an abelian variety *J. Alg. Geo.* **2** (1993), 569-601.

[2] Brumer, A. and Kramer, K., The conductor of an abelian variety,
*Compositio Math.* (1994).

[3] Ogg, A., Elliptic curves and wild ramification, *Amer. J. Math.*
**89** (1967), 1-21.

[4] Saito, T., Conductor, discriminant, and the Noether formula of
arithmetic surfaces, *Duke Math. J.* **57** (1988), 151-173.